# How to get a php drop down to list in Alpha Order

Tags: php, mysql, sql, wordpress

Im trying to modify a wordpress plugin to list a populated dropdown in alpha order can someone please help find a solution to help me modify the current code please see below

```
    <td>
            <select name="javo_event[parent_post_id]">

                <option value=""><?php _e('Not Set');?></option>


                <?php

                if( !empty($javo_get_items ) ){

                    foreach($javo_get_items as $item){

                        setup_postdata($item);

                        printf('<option value="%s"%s>%s</option>'

                            , $item->ID

                            , ( $javo_meta_query->_get('parent_post_id', 0) == $item->ID? ' selected':'')


                            , $item->post_title

                        );                  


                    };  // End Foreach      


                };      // End If

                ?>

            </select>

        </td>
```

Comment: no, not until you tell us exactly how this code ISN'T working. we're not here to read your mind, or do your job for you.

Comment: How are you getting $javo_get_items? These items should never be in the wrong order- when you get them you can specify the order.

Comment: @MarcB - I never said it wasn't working its working just fine im simply asking for some help for those who are willing and the help that I was requesting was a how to on making it populate in alphabetical order

Comment: @MikelBitson - The items are populating in order of how there were inputed in the database and im just attempting to arrange them in alpha order

Comment: @UserEnvy - right. And if you can say how you're getting them from the database, it might be possible to get the database to do the sorting for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to sort the array before you do the foreach.

```
<td>
        <select name="javo_event[parent_post_id]">
            <option value=""><?php _e('Not Set');?></option>
            <?php
            if( !empty($javo_get_items ) ){
                sort($javo_get_items);
                foreach($javo_get_items as $item){
                    setup_postdata($item);
                    printf('<option value="%s"%s>%s</option>'
                        , $item->ID
                        , ( $javo_meta_query->_get('parent_post_id', 0) == $item->ID? ' selected':'')
                        , $item->post_title
                    );                  
                };  // End Foreach      
            };      // End If
            ?>
        </select>
    </td>
```

Comment: Awesome that worked it put almost everything into alpha order except for some reason the last 11 items any idea on what may cause that to happen?

Comment: This really isn't ideal anyway. Now you've wasted memory and caused additional load time instead of just modifying the original query to include an ORDER BY statement.